# Wait for method to execute then execute the next code in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, wait, subscribe

I am trying to use the requestDetails variable outside the subscribe method but its showing "undefined"

service.ts

```
  requestDetails$ = new Subject<any>();
  updateApprovalMessage(message: string) {
  this.requestDetails$.next(message)
  }
```

component.ts

```
requestDetails:any

this.technicalRequestService.requestDetails$.subscribe(data=>{
this.requestDetails=data
console.log(this.requestDetails)
//here it is printing
}
console.log(this.requestDetails)
//but its is showing undefined
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Notice how undefined is logged first?

That's because your callback function hasn't been called yet. If you want to execute code after `this.requestDetails=data`, you will have to do so inside the function. You can of course call other methods from here as well.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.technicalRequestService.requestDetails$.subscribe(data=>{
    this.requestDetails=data;
    console.log(this.requestDetails);
    afterSettingRequestDetails();
  }
}

afterSettingRequestDetails(){
  console.log(this.requestDetails);
}
```

---

Or if you prefer `async` / `await`

```js
async ngOnInit() {
  this.requestDetails = await firstValueFrom(this.technicalRequestService.requestDetails$);
  console.log(this.requestDetails);
}
```

But this will only fire once, useful for single requests but not data streams.